# Clicking Compose button in Gmail using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, webdriver

The button pressing command doesn't work. It's finding the button, but isn't clicking the button. When clicking the button there should be a native page that opens within Gmail.

All the code below is attempting to click the button within the new contacts page of Gmail https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/1#contact/new

Inspecting the element  the div tag is div tabindex="0" aria-label="Email" data-tooltip="Email" aria-disabled="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id=":2l" class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-IF L3" role="button">div class="J-J5-Ji T-I-J3 Nz NS">/div>/div>

```
             System.out.println("Finding Button");
        driver.findElement(By.id(":2l")).click();

        System.out.println("printing button");
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id(":2l")));

        System.out.println("Finding button 2");
        WebElement composeBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-ax7 T-I-Js-IF L3']"));

        System.out.println("Clicking button 2");
        composeBtn.click();

       System.out.println("Button 2 Clicked");
        System.out.println(composeBtn.toString());

        System.out.println("Finding button 3");
        WebElement cBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class= 'J-J5-Ji T-I-J3 Nz NS']"));

        System.out.println("Clicking button 3");

        cBtn.click();
```

Please let me know if you can help me identify this button

Answer (score 1):

When I look at that page in the link you have provided, the compose button is grayed out and is not clickable. Having a program trying to click a button that a user could not click is still going to fail. Selenium will not and can not interact with objects that a user could not interact with (such as hidden fields, and in this case, grayed out buttons).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have mentioned that you'll need to add a new contact for the button to no longer be grayed out. Then when you press the button I am explaining the new contact will already be added in the email you're sending and you just need to update the subject and the body of the email and send.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses contains.

```
package testCase;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class GmailFileUpload 
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    WebElement element = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        File file = new File("G:\\Selenium\\All_Jars\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException 
    {
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("aavinashpande@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("password");



        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //click on compose
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3'] ")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='to']")).sendKeys("aavinashpande@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='subjectbox']")).sendKeys("aavinashpande@gmail.com");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Ar Au']//div"));
        element.click();
        element.sendKeys("Hi Avinash");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
}
     @After
    public void teardown() throws Exception 
    {
       driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the send button like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Send')]")).Click();
```

After that you can do a quit. Just have an extra pop up ask you to confirm leaving the account:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://mail.google.com/mail/logout?hl=en");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sent an Emil successfully through selenium automation using Gmail Account with the below script.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.in/";
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':jb']/div[@class='z0']/div")).click(); // Compose
selenium.type("//div[@class='wO nr l1']//textarea[@name='to']",       "vikramn@gmail.com"); // For To 

selenium.type("//div[@class='aoD az6']//input[@name='subjectbox']", "Wanted to SAY HI"); // For Subject
selenium.type("//div[@class='Ar Au']/div[@class='Am Al editable LW-avf']", "Hi Vikram");// For Message body
selenium.click("//div[@class='J-J5-Ji']/div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3']"); //send
```

Comment: Thank you! I notice the driver is from FireFox not Chrome. Happy it worked though

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to compose email using selenium web driver for gmail

```java
public void gmail() {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Email or phone']")).sendKeys("Your email");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Next']")).click();
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(password));

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label='Enter your password']")).sendKeys("your password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Next']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Compose')]")).click();
}
```

Comment: You can use above code to compose mail using selenium web driver for gmail

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='button' and text()='Compose']")).click();
```